# Assumption seems to break Sage's integrate() function; is this a bug?

Tags: sagemath

Consider the following Sage code (tested using Sage 8.6):

```
var('t')
var('a')
t.integrate(t, 0, a) # \int_{0}^{a} t dt
```

Output (as expected):

```
t
a
1/2*a^2
```

Next:

```
t.integrate(t, 0, 2*a - a^2) # 2*a - a^2 could be positive, negative, non-real(?)
```

Output (again, no problem):

```
1/2*a^4 - 2*a^3 + 2*a^2
```

Now suppose we give Sage a little more information. The following assumptions should guarantee that we're integrating over a real interval, and that the second (or "top") endpoint is strictly greater than the first ("bottom") endpoint. (Though as we have seen, Sage does not really need this information.)

```
assume(a, 'real')
assume(a > 1/2)
assume(a < 3/2) # now 0 < a < 2, so 2*a - a^2 > 0
t.integrate(t, 0, 2*a - a^2) # hangs, eventually produces RuntimeError
```

So, `.integrate()` succeeds when nothing is known about the endpoint, but then fails when given more information.

**My Question: Is this desired/expected behavior, or would it be considered a bug?**

Personally, I found it surprising: I expected that, if a command worked with no assumptions, then it should still work after adding assumptions (consistent assumptions that only narrow the scope of the problem).

*What follows is purely my own speculation; feel free to ignore.*

I also get a similar kind of problem if I do the following:

```
forget()
var('t'); var('a');
assume(a, 'real')
assume(a > 1/2)
assume(a < 3/2)
bool(2*a - a^2 > 0) # RuntimeError
```

It seems to me that $1/2 < a < 3/2$ implies $0 < a < 2$, which implies that $-a^2 + 2a > 0$. (The graph of the quadratic is a downward-opening parabola, with roots at $0$ and $2$.)  I am not surprised that Sage has trouble constructing this argument, so I am not surprised that the `bool()` command hangs.  But unfortunately this seems to break `.integrate()`, which was working otherwise.

So, I speculate that maybe the `.integrate()` method, when faced with an integral whose endpoints are known to be real, first tries to figure out which endpoint is greater?  But sometimes this process hangs, so the `.integrate()` process never terminates?

In our case, I think Sage assumes by default that `a` is complex-valued(?), and then it has no problem with the integral. So it seems like it should still work when `a` is in the real interval $(1/2, 3/2)$, which after all is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

By the way, the following works just fine:

```
forget()
var('t'); var('a');
assume(2*a - a^2 > 0)
print(bool(2*a - a^2 > 0))
t.integrate(t, 0, 2*a - a^2)
```

Edit: Also asked at ask.sagemath.org: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/52382/assumption-seems-to-break-integrate-is-this-a-bug/

Also, the following works:

```
t.integrate(t, 0, 2*a - a^2, algorithm='sympy')
```

(Based on guidance from the Sage development team, it seems that the problem is probably something to do with Maxima.)

Comment: Sage does indeed assume variables are complex, though the way Maxima handles this (which handles our integration) is less than ideal for certain situations.  You could try `algorithm='sympy'` in the integration and see what happens.  Also try ask.sagemath.org for possibly quicker responses, not a lot of Sage users/devs monitor this tag currently.

Comment: Actually I did try ask.sagemath. But I didn't get an answer there, so eventually I asked the Sage development team. (In fact it appears that you @kcrisman were personally involved in this discussion! This was around July 23-30.) You also suggested that I submit a Trac report, and maybe also report it upstream to the Maxima people, and link to that in the trac report. I recall that I had trouble with that because the Maxima site was down, or something weird like that... Well, eventually I lost interest. Sorry for not submitting the trac report--I guess I still could.

Comment: Haha!  I guess it's hard to keep track of all the support requests in the time of pandemic - Maxima's development happens on a different platform too.  It would be great to have you still report at least on Trac if you are able.

Comment: Hi again @kcrisman .  Uh, I think this might be fixed!  Before filing the Trac report, I thought I'd try an upgrade to the latest version.  I installed Sage 9.2 locally on my own Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS), and I can't reproduce the issue anymore!  I also tried running remotely at CoCalc, and the issue was present in Sage 8.9...but there was an option to upgrade and the issue disappeared when I did that.  So...problem solved, I guess?  Thank you very much for your kind attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been fixed in more recent versions of Sage!  Based on my experience, it seemed to be a problem in versions 8.6 and 8.9, but not in 9.2.  Since upgrading to 9.2 I can no longer reproduce this issue.

If you are experiencing a similar issue, I would recommend upgrading to a current version if possible.  (If that is not possible, a couple of work-arounds are suggested in the Question.)

Also, if you are using Sage online through [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/) it may give you an option to upgrade to a current version.  You can check what version you are running, by opening a notebook and executing a

`help()`

command.

Thank you very much to the Sage Development Team!